# Rotar filas de un dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

estoy intentando rotar las filas de una columna, para que el resultado sea, la primera fila sea la ultima, la segunda fila la primera y asi sucesivamente

Original

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podria hacer esto??

Comment: _Deja-vu_ ¿no acababa de responder yo esto mismo en un comentario? ¿QUé pasó con la pregunta original y con mi respuesta? En fin... repito... `df.A = np.roll(df.A, 1)`

Comment: Si, primero aparecio en inglés, luego la tradujo, pero no encuentro la originaj.